# Unususal problem with onscreen keyboard

Tags: onscreen-keyboard

Can anyone tell me please how to setup onscreen keyboard which I can use even after first and second login to the system. The problem is that I can't start screen keyboard when I logged in and loged off. There is no any icon to start it. Desktop environment KDE Plasma.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which version?

Comment: Try **Settings**, **Universal Access**, **Typing**, **Screen Keyboard**.